# Converting dictionary of dictionary of dictionary to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following nested dictionary:

```
In [3]: nested_dict
Out[3]:
{'2': {'lagtime': {'darkgreen': 210,
   'darkorange': 141,
   'pink': 142,
   'red': 141}}}
```

What I want to do is to create a data frame

```
0  2   darkgreen  lagtime    210
1  2  darkorange  lagtime    141
2  2        pink  lagtime    142
3  2         red  lagtime    141
```

I tried this but failed:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nested_dict)
```

I get this unexpected output:

```
Out[4]:
                                                         2
lagtime  {u'pink': 142, u'darkorange': 141, u'darkgreen...
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Are you getting an error or an unexpected output? In both cases, please print it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first need to transform the nested dictionary into a list of dictionaries or a dictionary of lists, and then only you can convert it to a DataFrame. Example (converting to a list of dictionaries) -

```
list_of_dict = []
for key, value in nested_dict.items():
    for key1, value1 in value.items():
        for key2,value2 in value1.items():
            list_of_dict.append({'A':key,'B':key1,'C':key2,'D':value2})

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict)
```

Use the correct column names instead of `'A'`, `'B'` , etc.

---

Example/Demo -

```
In [2]: nested_dict = {'2': {'lagtime': {'darkgreen': 210,
   ...:    'darkorange': 141,
   ...:    'pink': 142,
   ...:    'red': 141}}}

In [4]: list_of_dict = []

In [7]: for key, value in nested_dict.items():
   ...:     for key1, value1 in value.items():
   ...:         for key2,value2 in value1.items():
   ...:             list_of_dict.append({'A':key,'B':key1,'C':key2,'D':value2})
   ...:

In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict)

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
   A        B           C    D
0  2  lagtime   darkgreen  210
1  2  lagtime        pink  142
2  2  lagtime  darkorange  141
3  2  lagtime         red  141
```